# Python Nested List Comprehension with If Else

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to use a list comprehension to replace multiple possible string values in a list of values.

I have a list of column names which are taken from a `cursor.description`;

```
['UNIX_Time', 'col1_MCA', 'col2_MCA', 'col3_MCA', 'col1_MCB', 'col2_MCB', 'col3_MCB']
```

I then have `header_replace`;

```
{'MCB': 'SourceA', 'MCA': 'SourceB'}
```

I would like to replace the string values for `header_replace.keys()` found within the column names with the values.

I have had to use the following loop;

```
headers = []
for header in cursor.description:
    replaced = False
    for key in header_replace.keys():
        if key in header[0]:
            headers.append(str.replace(header[0], key, header_replace[key]))
            replaced = True
            break

    if not replaced:
        headers.append(header[0])
```

Which gives me the correct output;

```
['UNIX_Time', 'col1_SourceA', 'col2_SourceA', 'col3_SourceA', 'col1_SourceB', 'col2_SourceB', 'col3_SourceB']
```

I tried using this list comprehension;

```
[str.replace(i[0],k,header_replace[k]) if k in i[0] else i[0] for k in header_replace.keys() for i in cursor.description]
```

But it meant that items were duplicated for the unmatched keys and I would get;

```
['UNIX_Time', 'col1_MCA', 'col2_MCA', 'col3_MCA', 'col1_SourceA', 'col2_SourceA', 'col3_SourceA', 
'UNIX_Time', 'col1_SourceB', 'col2_SourceB', 'col3_SourceB', 'col1_MCB', 'col2_MCB', 'col3_MCB']
```

But if instead I use;

```
[str.replace(i[0],k,header_replace[k]) for k in header_replace.keys() for i in cursor.description if k in i[0]]
```

*@Bakuriu fixed syntax*

I would get the correct replacement but then loose any items that didn't need to have an string replacement.

```
['col1_SourceA', 'col2_SourceA', 'col3_SourceA', 'col1_SourceB', 'col2_SourceB', 'col3_SourceB']
```

Is there a pythonesque way of doing this or am I over stretching list comprehensions? I certainly find them hard to read.

Comment: What do you mean by `output`? The contents of `headers`?

Comment: I’d stick with the loops, and avoid the list comprehensions. My rule of thumb is that if you’re doing more than one thing in the comprehension, it’s probably best expanded into a loop with `.append`.

Comment: `cursor.description` holds a list of strings. `header[0]` holds a single character. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @HansZauber yes sorry I will use them to write the headers of a csv file using `csv.writer()`, normally I just do `writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])`

Comment: Nested list comprehensions (or generator expressions) are indeed hard to get right and hard to read - well, not "rocket science hard", but confusing enough to make the code harder to understand than a plain for loop. TL;DR : list comprehensions are great for simple, straighforward cases, for loops are better for the complex cases.

Comment: You do not need the `if k in i[0]` check at all. If the key is not in, then `replace` will just do nothing.

Comment: @tobias_k but without some form of `if` you end up with a duplicate of each element as you iterate through the keys.

Comment: @sneeu: or a generator that `yield`s the things that should end up in the list, even simpler than creating an empty list and appending to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[str.replace(i[0],k,header_replace[k]) if k in i[0] for k in header_replace.keys() for i in cursor.description]
```

this is a `SyntaxError`, because `if` expressions *must* contain the `else` part. You probably meant:

```
[i[0].replace(k, header_replace[k]) for k in header_replace for i in cursor.description if k in i[0]]
```

With the `if` at the end. However I must say that list-comprehension with nested loops aren't usually the way to go.
I would use the expanded `for` loop. In fact I'd improve it removing the `replaced` flag:

```
headers = []
for header in cursor.description:
    for key, repl in header_replace.items():
        if key in header[0]:
            headers.append(header[0].replace(key, repl))
            break
    else:
        headers.append(header[0])
```

The `else` of the `for` loop is executed when no `break` is triggered during the iterations.

---

I don't understand why in your code you use `str.replace(string, substring, replacement)` instead of `string.replace(substring, replacement)`. Strings have *instance* methods, so you them as such and not as if they were static methods of the class.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the `else` in a `for` loop that can be really useful. What is the purpose of the `_`?

Comment: @DaveAnderson I use tuple unpacking to avoid using `header[0]` all the time. But I just changed it because that would work only if `cursor.description` was a pair, but since it can have any number of elements I decided to roll that back. The symbol `_` doesn't have any particular meaning. It's just often used to mean "a variable that I'm not going to use, but is required". This convention was probably taken from Haskell where it *is* a special pattern that means "any value matches".

Answer (score 1):

If your data is exactly as you described it, you don't need nested replacements and can boil it down to this line:

```
l = ['UNIX_Time', 'col1_MCA', 'col2_MCA', 'col3_MCA', 'col1_MCB', 'col2_MCB', 'col3_MCB']
[i.replace('_MC', '_Source')  for i in l]

>>> ['UNIX_Time',
>>>  'col1_SourceA',
>>>  'col2_SourceA',
>>>  'col3_SourceA',
>>>  'col1_SourceB',
>>>  'col2_SourceB',
>>>  'col3_SourceB']
```

Comment: Unfortunately the common `MC` and `Source` isn't guaranteed it could be anything from `M00` through to `MFF` and the replacement values can be almost anything.

Comment: in that case I would advice to write specialized string replace function M_replace(source_string)

Comment: In that case I'd go with regular expressions instead of a huge dictionary of replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a function will be more readable:

```
def repl(key):
    for k, v in header_replace.items():
        if k in key:
            return key.replace(k, v)
    return key

print map(repl, names)
```

Another (less readable) option:

```
import re
rx = '|'.join(header_replace)
print [re.sub(rx, lambda m: header_replace[m.group(0)], name) for name in names]
```