# Python list comprehension with if else conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have a small (<100) list of chemical names called `detected_chems` .

And a second *much larger* (>1000) iterable; a dictionary `chem_db` containing **chemical names as the key**, and a dictionary of **chemical properties as the value**. Like this:

```
{'chemicalx':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},
 'chemicaly':{'property1':'stinks','property2':'toxic'}}
```

I am trying to match all the detected chemicals with those in the database and pull their properties.

I have studied these questions/answers but can't seem to apply it to my case (sorry)

- [Is it possible to use 'else' in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-list-comprehension)
- [if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)
- [if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)
- [Python Nested List Comprehension with If Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850508/python-nested-list-comprehension-with-if-else)

So I am making a list of results `res`, but instead of nested for loops with an `if x in` condition, I've created this.

```
res = [{chem:chem_db[chem]}
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       for chem in chem_db.keys()
       if det_chem in chem]
```

This works to an extent!

What I (think) am doing here is creating a list of dictionaries, which will have the key:value pair of chemical names (keys) and information about the chemicals (as a dictionary itself, as values), if the detected chemical is found somewhere in the chemical database (chem_db).

The problem is not all the detected chemicals are found in the database. This is *probably* because of misspelling or name variation (e.g. they include numbers) or something similar.

So to solve the problem I need to identify which detected chemicals are not being matched. I thought this might be a solution:

```
not_matched=[]
res = [{chem:chem_db[chem]}
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       for chem in chem_db.keys()
       if det_chem in chem else not_matched.append(det_chem)]
```

I am getting a syntax error, due to the `else not_matched.append(det_chem)` part.

I have two questions:

1) Where should I put the else condition to avoid the syntax error?

2) Can the `not_matched` list be built within the list comprehension, so I don't create that empty list first.

```
res = [{chem:chem_db[chem]}
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       for chem in chem_db.keys()
       if det_chem in chem else print(det_chem)]
```

What I'd like to achieve is something like:

```
in: len(detected_chems)
out: 20
in: len(res)
out: 18
in: len(not_matched)
out: 2

in: print(not_matched)
out: ['chemical_strange_character$$','chemical___WeirdSPELLING']
```

That will help me find trouble shoot the matching.

Comment: Can you remove unnecessary information from the question? You can do that by following [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks - I will remove unnecessary info not directly related to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should

```
if det_chem in chem or not_matched.append(det_chem)
```

but that being said if you clean up a bit as per comments I think there is a much more efficient way of doing what you want. The explanation of the above is that `append` returns `None` so the whole if-condition will evaluate to `False` (but the item still appended to the `not_matched` list)

Re: efficiency:

```
res = [{det_chem:chem_db[det_chem]}
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       if det_chem in chem_db or not_matched.append(det_chem)]
```

This should be *drastically* faster - the for loop on dictionary keys is an O(n) operation while dictionaries are used precisely because lookup is O(1) so instead of retrieving the keys and comparing them one by one we use the `det_chem in chem_db` lookup which is hash based

Bonus: dict comprehension (to address question 2)

I am not sure why a list of one-key-dicts is built but probably what needed is a dict comprehension as in:

```
chem_db = {1: 2, 4: 5}
detected_chems = [1, 3]
not_matched = []
res = {det_chem: chem_db[det_chem] for det_chem in detected_chems if
       det_chem in chem_db or not_matched.append(det_chem)}
# output
print(res) # {1: 2}
print(not_matched) # [3]
```

No way I can think of to build the `not_matched` list while also building `res` using a single list/dict comprehension.

Comment: Thank you. Please clarify:
1) The solution should be drastically faster than what?
2) should it be `if det_chem in chem_db.keys()` since it is a dictionary?

Comment: @Jimmy9zz: 1) much faster than having the `for chem in chem_db.keys()` - 2) nope checking if something is in a dict is done as `x in my_dict` that's O(1), checking the keys is O(len(keys))

Comment: I was going to write this answer as well. Much easier way to do so.

Comment: @Jimmy9zz: added section on dict comprehension

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension consists formally up to 3 parts. Let's show them in an example:

```
[2 * i          for i in range(10)         if i % 3 == 0]
```

1. The *first* part is an *expression* — and it may be (or used in it) the *ternary operator* (`x if y else z`)
2. The *second* part is a *list* (or more lists in nested `for` loops) to select values for a variable from it.
3. The *third* part (optional) is a *filter* (for selecting in the part 2) - and the `else` clause in **not allowed here!**

So if you want to use the `else` branch, you have to put it into the **first part**, for example

```
[2 * i  if i < 5  else 3 * i           for i in range(10)          if i % 3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax error comes from the fact that comprehension do not accepts `else` clauses.

You could eventually use the `... if ... else ...` ternary operator to determine the value to put in your comprehension result. Something like below:

```
not_matched=[]
res = [{chem:chem_db[chem]} if det_chem in chem else not_matched.append(det_chem)
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       for chem in chem_db.keys()]
```

But it would be a **bad idea** since you then would have `None` in your `res` for each *not matched*. This is because the `... if ... else ...` operator always returns a value, and in your case, the value would be the return value of the `list.append` method (= None).
You could then filter the `res` list to remove `None` values but... meh...

---

A **better solution** would be to simply keep your first comprehsion and get the difference between the original `chem` list and the `res` list:

```
not_matched = set(chems).difference(<the already matched chems>)
```

Note that I used a *the already matched chems* placeholder instead of a real chunk of code because the way your store your `res` is not pratical at all. Indeed it is a list of single-key-dictionaries which is a non-sens. The role of dictionary is to hold multiple values identified by keys.

A solution to this would be to make `res` a dictionary instead of a list, using a dict comprehension:

```
res = {chem: chem_db[chem]
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       for chem in chem_db.keys()
       if det_chem in chem}
```

Doing this, the *the already matched chems* placeholder could be replaced by `res.values()`

---

As an addition, even if **comprehensions** are a really cool feature in a lot of cases, they **are not a miraculous feature which should be used everywhere**.
And **nested comprehensions are a real pain** to read and should be avoided (in my opinion at least).

Comment: Thanks for your opinions too. As I stated in my question originally (later removed for brevity) I am purposely trying to use list comprehensions everywhere just for the sake of learning! Hopefully later, when I learn where they are/aren't suitable, I will have the ability to choose either them or nested for loops as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The below sample code would give you the desired output what you want. It is using a dictionary comprehension instead of a list comprehension to capture matched dictionary item info as a dictionary only. It is because you would need a dictionary of matched chemical items instead of a list. In the dictionary of matched items, it would be easier for you to get their properties later. Also, you don't need to use chem_db.keys() because the "in" operator itself searches the target in the entire sequence (be it a list or dictionary). And if the seq is a dict, then it matches the target with all the keys inside the dictionary.

Code:

```
detected_chems=['chemical_strange_character$$','chemical___WeirdSPELLING','chem3','chem4','chem5','chem6','chem7','chem8','chem9','chem10','chem11','chem12','chem13','chem14','chem15','chem16','chem17','chem18','chem19','chem20']
chem_db = {'chem1':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem2':{'property1':'stinks','property2':'toxic'},'chem3':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem4':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem5':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem6':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem7':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem8':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem9':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem10':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem11':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem12':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem13':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem14':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem15':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem16':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem17':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem18':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem19':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'},'chem20':{'property1':'smells','property2':'poisonous'}}

not_matched = []

res = {det_chem:chem_db[det_chem]
       for det_chem in detected_chems
       if det_chem in chem_db or not_matched.append(det_chem)}

print(len(detected_chems))
print(len(res))
print(len(not_matched))

print(not_matched)
```

The output:

```
20
18
2
['chemical_strange_character$$', 'chemical___WeirdSPELLING']
```

If any info is needed further, see to check out: [dictionary in python](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-dictionary/)